# Using SQL Case When with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-when

I've got a column in a query i wrote that looks like follows.

```
**RCPT_DATE**
NULL
2017-01-09 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
2016-09-05 00:00:00.000
```

What I want to do is get rid of `NULL` values and display 'Unavailable' and display 'No Rcpt' instead of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' values to make it look cleaner.

I've tried below but it doesn't do anything

```
CASE c.RCPT_DATE
    WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN ''
    WHEN NULL Then 'xxx'
    ELSE c.RCPT_DATE
    END AS RCPT_DATE,
```

I've tried,

```
CASE c.RCPT_DATE
    WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN NULL
```

this prints `NULL` instead of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' values but that's not what I Want.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are by any chance you dates stored as string? (I don't recommend it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I see this working is:

```
CASE
    WHEN c.RCPT_DATE = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 'No RCPT'
    WHEN C.RCPT_DATE IS NULL THEN 'Unavailable'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), C.RCPT_DATE, 121)
END
```

I've added the `CONVERT()` because you can't combine dates and strings in the same column.

Comment: You remembered to convert the receipt date to varchar, ensuring that all branches of the `CASE` expression have the same type +1

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen !

Comment: 100 points in one answer, and you're home in time for Cornflakes :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would be great cause then I'd also get the [Mortarboard badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard). 2 birds with 1 stone. And yes, then [**cornflakes**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIVNslHE_j4)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
CASE c.RCPT_DATE
WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 'No Rcpt'
ELSE ISNULL(CAST(c.RCPT_DATE as VARCHAR(50)),'Unavailable')
END AS RCPT_DATE
```

Hope it helps!

PS - edited, should work

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried this earlier.
Throws Error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: `ISNULL` will determine that its datatype is `datetime` since that's its first argument's type. This in turn, due to precedence, will mean that the type of the `CASE` expression is `datetime`. Which means this is going to error out being unable to convert `No Rcpt` and `Unavailable` to `datetime`. (Twas a nice idea though :-))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well spotted!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Well spotted indeed!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Does the use of `COALESCE` will solve the problem?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - unfortunately not. Although it's generally the preferred form (extends to more than 2 arguments, applies precedence rules), in this case precedence means we still end up selecting `datetime`.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - it didn't, I tested it before rejecting your edit proposal.